# how can i draw a torus specifying axis and vectors on it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, matlab

i tried several ways drawing a torus in a special direction with my desired features on it but couldn't reach my goal.  how can i draw a torus showing 3 axes and desired vectors and a theta on it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this a (La)TeX related question?

Comment: You need to specify more details of the desired features and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a torus and some axes is super easy with `pgfplots`.  You just plot the parametric equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis on top,axis lines=middle,axis equal image]
    \addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,domain=0:360,y domain=0:360]
      ({(3.5 + cos(y))*cos(x)}, {(3.5 + cos(y))*sin(x)}, {sin(y)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]